# How to hide legend selectively in a plotly line plot?

Tags: python, graph, plotly, visualization, linegraph

I'm struggling to hide the legend for some but not all of the lines in my line plot. Here is what the plot looks like now.

#### [Plot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz3fe.jpg)

[image]

Essentially I want to hide the legend for the light grey lines while keeping it in place for the coloured lines.

Here's my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=800, height=500, template='none')
fig.update_layout(title = 'Title', xaxis_title = 'Games', yaxis_title = 'Profit')

for team in rest_teams:
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y = df[team], name = team, line = {'color': '#F5F5F5'}))

for team in big_eight:
    line_dict = {'color': cmap[team]}
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y = df[team], name = team, line = line_dict))

fig.show()
```

I can update layout with

```
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

which hides the whole thing and isn't optimal. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your desired output correctly, you can use `showlegend = False` for the traces where you've set a grey color with `color = #F5F5F5`:

```
for c in cols1:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.index, y = df[c], line_color = '#F5F5F5',
                  showlegend = False))
```

And then leave that out for the lines you'd like colors assigned to, and make sure to include `name = c` in:

```
for c in cols2:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.index, y = df[c], 
                  name = c))
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


df = px.data.stocks()
df = df.set_index('date')

fig = go.Figure()

cols1 = df.columns[:2]
cols2 = df.columns[2:]

for c in cols1:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.index, y = df[c], line_color = '#F5F5F5',
                  showlegend = False))

for c in cols2:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.index, y = df[c], 
                  name = c))
fig.update_layout(template=template
fig.show()
```